# If $P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, Is there always a choice of points $q$, for $P$ is such that $\sigma(f,P,q) = \underline{s}(f,P)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

in my quest to understand Riemann's theory, I came across this question, and it made me think that I don't fully understand the theory

The title says it all.

> If $P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, does there always exist a choice of points $q$, for the associate partition $P$ is such that
> $$
> \sigma(f,P,q) = \underline{s}(f,P)\;?
> $$

Here $ \underline{s}(f, P) $ is the lower sum in the theory of Riemann integrability.

I think that this is **FALSE**

a Counter-example, using a function

lest assume tat exists $ f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $
and we will prove that P is a partition for $[a,b]$

let f be

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
       x, & x\ne 0 \\
      \ \beta, & x=0
   \end{cases}$
where $P=\{0,1\} $ partition of $[0,1]$

let see that

$ \underline{s}(f, P)=\sum_{i=1}^{\lambda}m_i\cdot A\cdot x_i = 0\cdot 1 = 0 $

but!

$\sigma(f,P,q) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(q_i)\Delta x_i= \begin{cases} 
       q, & q\ne 0 \\
      \ \beta, & q=0
   \end{cases}  $

but for all q that we will take
$f(g)$ will never be equal to zero
$f(g) \ne 0 $

therefore

$$ \sigma(f,P,q) \ne 0 \ne \underline{s}(f,P)\ \Rightarrow \sigma(f,P,q) \ne \underline{s}(f,P) $$

**THE NOTATION**
$\sigma(f,P,q)$ is referring to the Darbuex integral where q is the choice of points, p is the partition and f is the function

Comment: What is the question

Comment: Is there always a choice of points q, for P such that ?

Comment: Can you define the notation $\sigma(f, P, q)$?  If my guess for that notation is correct, you should consider the function $f$ given by $f(a) = a+1$ and $f(x) = x$ for $x > a$.

Comment: Can you write down explicitely the definition of $\underline{s}(f,P)$ ? Also, what have you tried ?